# Combine Regular Expressions #2

Tags: c#, regex

Please help how to combine the below two regular expressions

a) `@"(?<=\.Value\[)(.*)(?=\])"`

Above regular expression takes out a substring after .Value and it truncates the '[' and ']' brackets from the substring.

b) `@"[^\{*\}*$]+"`

Removes all the '{' and '}' braces from the beginning and end of the above substring. The substring can have zero or more number of occurrences of '{' and '}'characters.

E.g.

> {{server/Y2KCluster1:[]ServerServerStatusState}}.Value[{{{server/Y2KCluster2:[]ServerServerStatusSecondsTillShutdown}}}]

After applying 1st regular expression it returns as

> [{{{server/Y2KCluster2:[]ServerServerStatusSecondsTillShutdown}}}]

After applying 2nd regular expression then it return as

> server/Y2KCluster2:[]ServerServerStatusSecondsTillShutdown

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs you are using and what you would be expecting.

Comment: Maybe this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145651/combining-these-two-regular-expressions-into-one) will help

Comment: {{server/Y2KCluster1:[]<Organizes>Server<HasComponent>ServerStatus<HasComponent>State}}.Value[{{{server/Y2KCluster2:[]<Organizes>Server<HasComponent>ServerStatus<HasComponent>SecondsTillShutdown}}}]

After applying first regular expression then it return as
[{{{server/Y2KCluster2:[]<Organizes>Server<HasComponent>ServerStatus<HasComponent>SecondsTillShutdown}}}]

After applying 2nd regular expression then it return as
server/Y2KCluster2:[]<Organizes>Server<HasComponent>ServerStatus<HasComponent>SecondsTillShutdown

Comment: Edit your question @ShibuVeerappallil, instead of posting as comment

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression

```
(?<=\.Value\[)(?:{*)([^}]+)(?=[\]}])
```

will

- find the substring after `.Value[`
- and match any number of `{` characters greedily
- greedily match everything before a `}` character - returned in group 1
- end before a `}` or `]` character

demo: https://regex101.com/r/mA7pH2/1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution and it return as `code` {{{{server/S2KCluster2:[]<Organizes>Server<HasComponent>ServerStatus<HasComponent>SecondsTillShutdown}.

Comment: @Shibu look at the [table tab at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c.Value%5c%5b)(%3f%3a%7b*)(%5b%5e%7d%5d%2b)(%3f%3d%5b%5c%5d%7d%5d)&i=%7b%7bserver%2fY2KCluster1%3a%5b%5dServerServerStatusState%7d%7d.Value%5b%7b%7b%7bserver%2fY2KCluster2%3a%5b%5dServerServerStatusSecondsTillShutdown%7d%7d%7d%5d) and see that the result you desire is correctly captured in $1 aka group 1, as I mentioned in my answer and as is shown on regex101

Comment: Thanks its working now. Previously i didn't extract the value $1. Now i extracted the $1 value as .Groups[1].value. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks Keith Hall.

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
\.Value\[\{*((?:\[[^\]]*\]|.)*?)}*\]
```

looks for a match to the Value *property*. Then matches a `[` followed by any number of `{`. **Then**, and this is where the *work* is done, in a capture group - get any of

- `\[[^\]]*\]` - a `[` followed by anything up to a `]` (matching brackets - in your example simply `[]`)
- `.` any character

repeat this non-greedy until any number of `}` followed by a `]`.

The result is captured in group 1.

Regards